# RoR: Nested Resources with Polymorphic Association (comments system)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I'm following [Ryanb's polymorphic association video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised) to implement a comment system. However, I'm using nested resources, and would like some help

I mimiced most of the stuff in the video but instead of this:

```
def load_commentable
  resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
  @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
end
```

I did this:

```
def load_commentable
    @commentable = params[:commentable].classify.constantize.find(commentable_id)
end

def commentable_id
  params[(params[:commentable].singularize + "_id").to_sym]
end
```

and my routes are as follows:

```
resources :users do
  resources :comments, :defaults => { :commentable => 'user' }
  resources :styles do
    resources :comments, :defaults => { :commentable => 'style' }
  end
end
```

I'm able to display my comments system correctly, but my issue is when I create a new comment in my styles pages

example: `localhost:3000/users/1/styles/11`

It gets redirected to: `localhost:3000/styles/11/comments`

and I get an error **NoMethodError in CommentsController#create**

```
undefined method `classify' for nil:NilClass
```

**EDIT for additional information**

This is my CommentsController

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_commentable

  def index
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  def new
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new
  end

  def edit
    @comment = @commentable.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @comment = @commentable.comments.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated comment."
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private
def get_commentable
    @commentable = params[:commentable].classify.constantize.find(commentable_id)
end

def commentable_id
  params[(params[:commentable].singularize + "_id").to_sym]
end
```

and full trace is

```
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:38:in `get_commentable'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__3190436191390106396__process_action__768140268660897649__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3801355732529113779__call__1297539504005695456__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/andrewliu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/andrewliu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/andrewliu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: Could you post CommentsController#create code and the full stacktrace of the exception?

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead.

```
def get_commentable
   klass = [Style].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"] }
   @commentable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
end
```

Also you could try breaking up your routes by shallow nesting them. More on this [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

```
resources :users do
  resources :comments
  resources :styles
end
resources :styles do
    resources :comments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is not passing in a parameter called params[:commentable] so that becomes nil and that's why the error is arising.

Comment: ohh I see, right now I have a form button that is `<%= f.submit %>` from a  `<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>` in a views page `views/comments/_form.html.erb`. I can render this page (`<%= render "comments/form" %>`) from another page such as `views/users/show.html.erb` and my button works as it should, but how do I fix the submit button if I'm rendering the form page from the nested resources `style`? How do I tell the submit button that this time it is in a nested resources? I hope my questions make sense